# Get Kendo Window in the drag event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-window

I'm binding to the `drag` event of my windows.

```
$("#@Model.Name").data("kendoWindow").dragging._draggable.bind("drag", function (e) {    
var wnd = $("#@Model.Name").data("kendoWindow");
```

Now, I'd like to write one function and bind all of the windows to that function, so I cannot hard-code the window's `id`. How can I get the sender window in that function?

I've tried the followings:

```
$(e.target).closest('.k-window').data('kendoWindow')
$(e.currentTarget).closest('.k-window').data('kendoWindow')
$(e.sender).closest('.k-window').data('kendoWindow')
```

all of them return `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `.k-window-content`

```
$('.k-window-content').each(function(){
    $(this).data("kendoWindow")...
});
```

Edit, OP wanted to use the `dragging._draggable.bind` method:

```
$("#id").data("kendoWindow").dragging._draggable.bind("drag", function (e) {
    e.currentTarget.parent().find(".k-window-content").data("kendoWindow")...
});
```

Comment: I won't have the `dragging._draggable.bind` with that selector. My problem is to get the window inside the event.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hkv07esv/), I want to override the selector inside the function to work with `e`, not a hard-coded value.

Comment: This is one way, currently looking for more. `$(e.sender.element.context).data("kendoWindow")`

Comment: Another: `e.currentTarget.parent().find(".k-window-content").data("kendoWindow")`

Comment: Done. No problem, did the first suggestion not work?

Comment: By the way, can you please explain how did you get them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87631/discussion-between-user1102901-and-akbari).